# Replacing commas in text inside tags in R

Tags: r, regex, string, text

I have a text file (`my.txt`) with the following contents that I wish to process in `R`.

```
Lorem ipsum tag:[value_0], dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua tag:[value_01, value_02, value_03].
Ut enim ad minim veniam, tag:[value_04, value_05, value_06, value_07] quis nostrud exercitation, tag:[value_08, value_09, value_10].
```

I wish to process strings inside tags (`tag:[ * ]`).
Values inside the tags are
comma separated made up of
alphanumeric characters and punctuations (except commas and brackets).
The number of values inside a tag is variable (1 or more).
I wish to change the commas with `]+[`.

The outcome I wish to have is as follows:

```
Lorem ipsum tag:[value_0], dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua tag:[value_01]+[value_02]+[value_03].
Ut enim ad minim veniam, tag:[value_04]+[value_05]+[value_06]+[value_07] quis nostrud exercitation, tag:[value_08]+[value_09]+[value_10].
```

All I have been able to figure out is to capture the contents of the tags.

```
gsub(
  pattern = paste0(
    "tag:\\[([^]]*)\\]"
  ),
  replacement = "\\1",
  x = readLines("my.txt")
)
```

I cannot simply find and replace commas since there are commas outside the tags.
Is there a way to process `\\1` further to replace commas with `]+[`?
Is there a way to achieve my goal using base R?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `stringr` package using nested replaces. First find the tags, then for each of the tags, replace the commas. `str_replace_all` allows you to pass a function for transformation rather than a string.

```
input <- c(
  "orem ipsum tag:[value_0], dolor sit amet",
  "consectetur adipiscing elit",
  "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua tag:[value_01, value_02, value_03].",
  "Ut enim ad minim veniam, tag:[value_04, value_05, value_06, value_07] quis nostrud exercitation, tag:[value_08, value_09, value_10]."
)

stringr::str_replace_all(input, "tag:\\[[^\\]]*\\]", function(x) {
  stringr::str_replace_all(x, ", ", "]+[")
})
```

which returns

```
[1] "orem ipsum tag:[value_0], dolor sit amet"                                                                                                 
[2] "consectetur adipiscing elit"                                                                                                              
[3] "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua tag:[value_01]+[value_02]+[value_03]."                                  
[4] "Ut enim ad minim veniam, tag:[value_04]+[value_05]+[value_06]+[value_07] quis nostrud exercitation, tag:[value_08]+[value_09]+[value_10]."
```

Comment: This is a very clever solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions.

In the question a comma within square brackets is always followed by a space and I assumed that is the general case but if a comma within square brackets can be followed by a non-space then remove the space after the comma in the pattern in each solution.

**1) gsubfn** This one-liner uses `gsubfn` which finds the matches to the pattern given in the first argument, passes it to the function (which may be specified as a formula) in the second argument and replaces each match with the output of the function.

Here it matches `tag:[` followed by a string until the next nearest `]` and uses `gsub` to perform the required replacement within that.

```
library(gsubfn)

gsubfn("tag:\\[.*?\\]", ~ gsub(", ", "]+[", x), Lines)
```

**2) gsub** It can be done in a single `gsub` although note the caveat below.  It looks for comma followed by space followed by any number of non-square brackets followed by a right square bracket.  If a left square bracket comes first or no right square bracket is encountered it won't match. Everything except the comma space is within a zero width lookahead -- the lookahead won't be regarded as part of the pattern so only the comma space is replaced and the lookahead part continues to be processed for more comma and space character sequences.

(Unfortunately lookbehind does not support repetition characters so we can't use the same idea to check for a preceding `tag:[` .  Thus this is not completely safe although the checks it does do seem sufficient for the example input in the question and maybe for your actual input as well.)

This only uses base R.

```
gsub(", (?=[^][]*\\])", "]+[", Lines, perl = TRUE)
```

**2a)** This variation of (2) is longer than (2) but it does check for `tag:[` and still uses only base R.  It assumes that there are no brace brackets in the input.  If there are brace brackets use some other characters that are not in the input, e.g. < and > .  First it replaces the `tag:[...]` with `{...}`.  Then it performs the substitution as in (2) but using brace brackets and finally it converts back.

```
Lines2 <- gsub("tag:\\[(.*?)\\]", "{\\1}", Lines)
Lines3 <- gsub(", (?=[^][{}]*})", "]+[", Lines, perl = TRUE)
gsub("\\{(.*?)\\}", "tag:[\\1]", Lines2)
```

Comment: Have added variation 2a.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (late to the game) that specifically works only on sections within the brackets without having to do more pattern matching on them. (I'm not saying the other answers are not good, just an alternative with some specificity).

```r
txt <- c("Lorem ipsum tag:[value_0], dolor sit amet,", "consectetur adipiscing elit,", "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua tag:[value_01, value_02, value_03].", "Ut enim ad minim veniam, tag:[value_04, value_05, value_06, value_07] quis nostrud exercitation, tag:[value_08, value_09, value_10].")
expect <- c("Lorem ipsum tag:[value_0], dolor sit amet,", "consectetur adipiscing elit,", "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua tag:[value_01]+[value_02]+[value_03].", "Ut enim ad minim veniam, tag:[value_04]+[value_05]+[value_06]+[value_07] quis nostrud exercitation, tag:[value_08]+[value_09]+[value_10].")

gre <- gregexpr("\\[[^]]+\\]", txt)
regmatches(txt, gre) <- regmatches(txt, gre) |>
  lapply(gsub, pattern = ", *", replacement = "]+[")
txt
# [1] "Lorem ipsum tag:[value_0], dolor sit amet,"                                                                                               
# [2] "consectetur adipiscing elit,"                                                                                                             
# [3] "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua tag:[value_01]+[value_02]+[value_03]."                                  
# [4] "Ut enim ad minim veniam, tag:[value_04]+[value_05]+[value_06]+[value_07] quis nostrud exercitation, tag:[value_08]+[value_09]+[value_10]."
identical(txt, expect)
# [1] TRUE
```

Regex:

```
"\\[[^]]+\\]"
 ^^^     ^^^  the literal brackets, escaped since they are used for regex classes
    ^^^^^     one or more of anything other than the close bracket
```

`gregexpr` returns a list of character ranges, and `regmatches` by itself retrieves the substrings (as demoed above). `regmatches<-` replaces the substrings with the altered strings, and conveniently the new strings do not need to be the same number of characters per substring as in the original.